# SQL Server 2016 drops query cache

Tags: sql-server, caching, query-performance, sql-execution-plan

I have a SQL Server 2016 environment with high availability on. When I check the query plan cache, I see that SQL Server is constantly clearing the cache. The query below returns only 5 to 10 records sometimes 0 records.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans decp
```

I scripted all database objects (stored procedures, triggers..) to see if there's a command anywhere that drops the cache, but I could not find any.

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any extended event that catches when the cache is cleared?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same proble, reducing Max Memory from 60 GB to 55 GB make the server performing better.

(batch per seconds) / (compilation per seconds) is about 4% (before the changes was 15/20%)